# Not getting all rows in resultset

Tags: java, resultset

I am using the following code to get the data from the database in a resultset:

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());   

Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:1521:DB", "User","pass_01");
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();   
resultset = statement.executeQuery("select * from employee"); 
System.out.println("Records Exist "+resultset.next()); 
System.out.println(resultset.getRow());
while (resultset.next()) {
    System.out.println(resultset.getInt(1) + " " +
    resultset.getInt(2) + " " + 
    resultset.getInt(3) + " " + 
    resultset.getString(4));
}
```

But I am getting only one row though there are two rows in the database table. What am I missing here?

Comment: are you sure table contains two rows?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is because you are calling `rs.next()` before the loop. It returns a boolean and one row is loses its chance to be printed because of this statement.

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:1521:DB", "User","pass_01");
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();   
resultset = statement.executeQuery("select * from employee"); 
while (resultset.next()) {
    System.out.println(resultset.getInt(1) + " " +
    resultset.getInt(2) + " " + 
    resultset.getInt(3) + " " + 
    resultset.getString(4));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take off the ResultSet.next() while printing. This makes the RS cursor to point to a new row

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it by using the 'do...while' loop instead of while. You can use the following approach.

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * from employee");

if (!rs.next()) {
    System.out.println("ResultSet is empty...."); 
} else { 
    do { 
        String record = rs.getString("emp_name");
        System.out.println(record); 
       } while (rs.next());
    }
```

Comment: Hello @nabinghatani , welcome to SO! It is hard for me to see any additional info, beyond the one given in the accepted answer. If you really want to illustrate an approach using 'do ... while' (certainly possible --- while equivalent) please do so and come up with a short code example illustrating your point.